# Drawing continuous modular line in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a one dimensional vector space `V=span{(1,\sqrt 2)}` and I want to draw its image mod 1 under a matrix `A`. Is there a way to draw **continuously** (unlike [this question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168896/using-modulo-operation-to-draw-graph)) the line beginning in `(0,0)`, passing through `(1,\sqrt(2)-1)` and so on?

Roughly speaking that should look like this (modulu my slopy hands):

[image]

Comment: `\clip(0,0)rectangle(1,1);` and then draw slope-√2 lines that passes integral coordinates.

Comment: @Symbol1 what do you mean by "passes integral coordinates"? the red line does not intersect the sides of the square only in integer points. Can you please draw a MWE?

Comment: Given that the full picture would be indistinguishable to the eye from a filled square, how many times round the modular process would you like to go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\tikz{
    \clip(0,0)rectangle(10,10);
    \foreach\x in{0,...,10}{
        \foreach\y in{0,...,20}{
            \draw(-\x0,-\y0)--+(100,141.421);
        }
    }
}

\end{document}
```

[image: slope √2 line mod 1]

A proof that this works

```
\tikz{
    \clip(0,0)rectangle(10,10);
    \foreach\x in{0,...,3}{
        \foreach\y in{0,...,10}{
            \draw(-\x0,-\y0)--+(100,141.421);
        }
    }
    \foreach\x in{1,...,5}{
        \draw[blue,dotted]({mod(7.07106*\x,10)},0)--+(0,10);
    }
    \foreach\x in{1,...,3}{
        \draw[red,dotted](0,{mod(4.14213*\x,10)})--+(10,0);
    }
}
```

[image: slope √2 line mod 1 with tracking help]

An animation that shows how line grow

```
\foreach\frame in{0,...,40}{
    \tikz{
        \clip(0,0)rectangle(10,10);
        \foreach\x in{-5,...,5}{
            \foreach\y in{-8,...,8}{
                \fill[shift={(\x0,\y0)},scale=\frame/10]
                    (-.2,.2)--(10,14.1421)--
                    (.2,-.2)--(-10,-14.1421)--cycle;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: a growing "line" that wraps]

Bonus

[image: growing black line and then white line]

Comment: `-+(100,41.421)` could be better...

Comment: Doesn't that change the slope to √2-1? I mean, I am not sure if OP wants √2 or √2-1 though.

Comment: Exact: the first sentence is unclear ! :-)

Comment: I think the sqrt(2)-1 is the result of applying the matrix A to the original line.

Comment: The line will start at (0, 0) if the foreaches start from 0 (my bad not noticing that earlier).

Comment: I said that my brain wasn't working! Now that it is, I agree that this is the right approach.